# Method to find Chrome Bookmarks next available ID number?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Anyone know how to get the next index number available for a Chrome bookmark? The closest I can come right now is pulling the ID of the most recently added and increasing by 1. That works until a user creates a bookmark and immediately deletes it. Then, the id index increases by 1 but most recent returns the most recent bookmark still existing and the number is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, no such method. If you explain what you are trying to achieve maybe someone can suggest an alternate route.

Comment: I'm allowing a user to create a new bookmark and at the same time writing some meta data to local storage. The id is the linking identifier since it is the key for Chrome. I tried having Chrome create the new bookmark first and then grabbing using getRecent but asynchronous nature of function made the result somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: Can't you just listen to `bookmarks.onCreated` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bookmarks created in your extension you can use the callback of [chrome.bookmarks.create](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html#method-create) which returns a [BookmarkTreeNode](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html#type-BookmarkTreeNode) (that contains the attribute id).

For bookmarks created by the user outside of your extension (*and in your extension*) you can listen to [chrome.bookmarks.onCreated](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html#event-onCreated) which will both return a string id and a BookmarkTreeNode.

To get the first id (eg: the first time the extension runs) you could create a bookmark, get the id and then delete it. This might not be needed if you just want to link metadata to bookmarks, the onCreated event should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, both you and Serg made a good point. I could just maintain a variable in the background listening and taking on each create. Thanks!